# while using BufferedReader to read 2 numbers in same line I was having an Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 3"

Tags: java

Iam new to BufferedReader. I was trying to take input of 2 numbers in the same line **for ex: 2 3**. For that I have written the below code.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        int M = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
        System.out.println("N="+N+"M="+M);
    }
}
```

So Iam encountering the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2 3"                                                 
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)                                            
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)                                                                             
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)                                                                             
        at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

What's wrong with the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assume that I give you the string "2 3". Then I ask you to tell me which number this string represents. What would you say? 23? 2? or 3? Long story short, this is the error. You can't extract a number from a string if the string contains non-numeric characters. In you case, whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually I have a doubt that what do I get if I use trim(). Is it an array of objects returned after using trim() after removing all the white spaces.

Comment: `trim()`: *Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking in multiple inputs on the same line, you should define a character that will be used to separate inputs. In your example, it seems like this is done through whitespace.

You need to create an array of responses from the single line input as a string using `split()`, and then assign them to the variables you need using `Integer.parseInt()`.

```java
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create BufferedReader and two ints
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N, M;

        // Take in inputs from user, and split them into an array using whitespace
        // '\\s+' matches at any whitespace size
        String[] inputs = bufferedReader.readLine().split("\\s+");

        N = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
        M = Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]);

        System.out.println("N=" + N + " M=" + M);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rhys Wootton and george. So the trim() return a string after removing all the whitespaces. and split() return a string array after seperating all spaces. Thank you both. :-)

Comment: One more thing. Which is better to use StringTokenizer or Split(). Which is more feasible and efficient?

Comment: String.split() is the way to go. StringTokenizer is only kept in there for  compatibility reasons as seen in the Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html